# C# - Most effective way to periodically read last part of a file

Tags: c#, readfile

I want to periodically read a log file that is also being written to. 
The program will be periodically reading the log file contents and parsing it to extract some values. But I do not want to read the whole file each time.

Is there a way to read a file from a particular line onwards?

For example at the first read the file has 100 lines. I note this value and next time I read I start reading from line 100 onwards and store the line number of the current file.

Is there an efficient way to do this?
The log file will grow to about 100MB and I need to read about every 5 seconds. So it wouldn't be that efficient to read the complete file each time.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might look at Tail.NET http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7568/Tail-NET

Comment: You could partition the file into multiple files or a DB intended for such a purpose.  Although, I'm not sure how much benefit that provides with only 100MB file.  Streams tend to have start indexes.  Why not just use that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for this, where offset is going to be how much you want backtrack. Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx)

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    fs.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.End);
}
```

Now the filestream is pointing to however far back in the file you set 'offset' to be, and you can read from there.

Comment: ...hah, I'm two minutes too slow ;)

Comment: @bland Thank you. I will have look in to this method. Looks like this could work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If the log is only appended, you can try opening a file in read-only mode without a lock. That way other processes can write to it while you read it.

```
var fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: If you remember the length of the file, you may be able to `Seek` to that location on the next read.

Answer (score 3):

Seek can do this well. But I want to provide other onward way.

```
    public static void Read()
    {
        var fs = new FileStream(@"G:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        int lastReadCount = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var totalCountOfFile = fs.Length;
            if (lastReadCount < totalCountOfFile)
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024];
                int count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                lastReadCount += count;
                Display(buffer);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }

    private static void Display(byte[] buffer)
    {
        var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Where(p=>p != 0).ToArray());
        Console.Write(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For something fast and dirty, I use this.  In this case it's a log dump - I don't really care about how many lines I get, I just want a bunch at the end (`numBytes`) :

```
cmdLogReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(cmdLogFileIn);

if (cmdLogReader.BaseStream.Length < (numBytes - 1)) {
    return cmdLogReader.ReadToEnd;
} else {
    cmdLogReader.BaseStream.Seek(-numBytes, System.IO.SeekOrigin.End);
    cmdLogReader.ReadLine();
    return cmdLogReader.ReadToEnd;         
}
```

You could always save the `BaseStream.Length` at the beginning and use that to calculate how far back to go next time (ie: `numBytes` becomes `BaseStream.Length - previousBaseStreamLength` or whatever), that would let sequential calls grab whatever has been added since the last read.

You may have to skip the `ReadLine` call if you do this since it's really only there to move up to the nearest line after backtracking a random amount.  If you know you're going to land on a line boundary then you can just `ReadToEnd`.

This is a bit of a gritty implementation, but it's very fast which is why I use it.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of BaseStream.Length property and using this method to read the file. I will have a look in to this method.